# In-App-Billing Issues  in android 

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have some doubts regarding In-Application-Billing in android:

- Can i test it with different product IDs without paying $25
- In below link there is option to add product after it has been published to market then how it will added to program UI like ListView or Spinner to show to user?

  http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup
- From where we put the value in Purchase database initially.How should its change if more than one person using app.As its on Device so if same iTem will purchase by two person how they will synchronize?
- How to generate ProductID?

Comment: @Fedor: why you edited this question? previous format was good

Comment: Most of the answers to this question are now outdated.  People should look for more recent information, since the latest in-app billing version, IAB3, is significantly different from the one available at the time these answers were posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You must have an Android Market publisher account to test In-app Billing in your application. Thus, you have to pay Google the $25 registration fee. As for product cost itself, there are 4 `android.test.*` pre-designated product ids that emulate purchase activities but aren't the real thing. To test with your own product id, you must use a real credit card and the **minimum** price varies based on currency conversion rates. The current default $1.34 in the sample still works fine.
2. You can add a product to an application and expect this to work **only if** it is properly defined in **both** the application *and* your Android Market publisher account.
3. Answer #2 basically answers your question #3. You must plan ahead and make sure that product ids are "upward compatible".
4. You can create any productID that you like, as long as it is unique within your application, i.e. no other in-app billing item has that ID. It's a string, so you can just call it "ItemNumberOne", "iAmSoUnique", "myVerSpecialService", etc. Google chose sword_001 and potion_001 for their real items in the billing sample.

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad You are very welcome. I was in your situation a few weeks ago. Google's In-app Billing is the most complex and difficult to implement (correctly) payment system I have ever seen, and the documentation on it leaves something to be desired. If we don't help each other, it will never take off. Now, with a few weeks of experimenting with it, I am happy I can help others. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Bill The Ape hello I am also working on the which require in app purchase i had read the documentation given in the official website & Do exactly like that like i had made an Android Market publisher account then create a product list & then upload the apk in the market But it doesn'nt show me the Product list.It only Show me the buy Button How can i resolve this problem .help me Thanks in advance..

Comment: @BillTheApe : please tell me is there a limit for creating product IDS or we can as many Productid'S as we want/need ?? please reply..its urget

Comment: @Amandeepsingh please tell me is there a limit for creating product IDS or we can as many Productid'S as we want/need ?? please reply..its urget

Comment: @BillTheApe i had made one product on consol now i am going to test it  but when i test from device it's display me sample title and price is 0.99$ can you tell me why this proble arise i had product with name pro version but it's display me sample title

Answer (score 3):

Answer for 3)

The product id namespace is only for your application. Thus it must be unique within your application but you are free to name it to what you like. The product id makes it possible for you application to distinguish between different in-app-purchase items for the same application.

The product id is the string passed from the Google billing service to your application upon purchase.

The identifier is specified in the developer console as "In-app Product ID". It is up to you to match this identifier within your application and take appropriate actions.

Comment: thank for response ,I have studied sample given on android developer site.I studied it but i did not get a way how to insert product in Database.And as you know product can be added after publishing so how to synchronize and display them in UI.Can you elaborate them a bit

Comment: Thanx for responce but still some doubt are not clear.One upvote for both

Answer (score 3):

1) You have to buy the items while testing. However you can charge much less then $25, and then you can refund yourself through google checkout. You even get the transaction fees back!

2) Your app cannot retrieve the available in app-purchases from the market. Either have them statically in the app, or retrieve them from your own server.

3) answered nicely by mach1980

4) You can just arbitrarily name them however I want. Or have I misunderstood this question?

Cheers.

Comment: But their is way to add product after uploading App in market.What about this?

Comment: While you can add additional in app purchases, they cannot dynamically be retrieved from the market and displayed by the app. One alternative is to release an updated app which holds an updated list of the available purchases, or you could make your app retrieve them from another server. In the official sample from google (Dungeons), they have a static list of available purchases in the app.

Comment: However you can charge much less then $25.what is the mean of that line mention above in your answer

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: I meant if you want to test out your code and perform in app purchases on your own app. You can set the price to the allowed minimum, and then refund yourself through Google Checkout.

Answer (score 2):

1.) Yes, you can, for example, set 0.01$ price per item

2.) You need to implement any items, what you sell, in your app, and get it by productID

4.) Set the name like "com.ads.free" - you can put any string what you want. It's an identificator, which helps your app find the right item in google billing server to purchase it.